# How can I programatically open a new page in a new tab from my codebind file in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, code-behind

How can I programatically open a page in a new tab from my code behind file in ASP.NET after clicking on a button in my first page?
Hopefully, from the new page I could also get to the Session[] array.

Comment: Does that could involved a reload of the current page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Code behind" runs on the server, no browser instances there to open/use.
Javascript runs in the browser, on the client's computer, it can open a new tab.
If you want, you will have to write a piece in C# that will generate a JavaScript snippet with the **window.open** Command.

Answer (score 6):

Kelsey's code is correct, but is now depricated, the suggested way to do it now is to use the ScriptManager's methods like this.

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "SomeNameForThisScript",
           "window.open('YourPage.aspx');", true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just register a window.open command in the start client script.

In your C# client side code (event):

```
RegisterStartupScript("SomeNameForThisScript", "window.open('YourPage.aspx');");
```

When you page is served up, the startup script will fire and open a new window.  You can customize how the [window.open works via attributes](http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/javascript/popupwindows.html).

Answer (score 0):

How about   Response.Redirect("~/formname.aspx?Parameters=" + yourparamater); ?