# Open page in new tab from code behind

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to open a page in new tab from code behind?

Comment: Please check this url:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530274/asp-net-open-new-tab-in-browser-from-codebehind

Comment: this solution set sth for ClientClick but i want to write code in method and call it

Comment: This is what you after [target Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Comment: I wan to write it in code behind not use for an html or asp control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a hyperlink you can just add `target="blank"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
  Response.Write '<script type="text/javascript"> window.open(url);
```

or take a look at [**jems answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5530274/asp-net-open-new-tab-in-browser-from-codebehind)

or you can use [**window.open command**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215505/how-can-i-programatically-open-a-new-page-in-a-new-tab-from-my-codebind-file-in)

Comment: the first one, jems answer set url for OnClientClick but i want to use it in a function and call it when i need